# How is the `get_sidebar` function meant to be used to call a 2nd sidebar?

Tags: theme-development, sidebar

What's the proper way to call a second sidebar in the main home of my blog?
And I mean 2 sidebars at the same time....

I might edit the question when I get further info, but now I'm feeling completely lost.

Comment: A second sidebar is a bit fague. Position makes a big diffirence here. Where do you need to place this second sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) really does [is load a file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L131). Which file you load depends on how you call the function. `get_sidebar()` will load `sidebar.php` from the theme directory. `get_sidebar('two');` will load `sidebar-two.php` from the theme directory. "Theme directory" means the same folder as should have `style.css`. That is all there is to using the function.

Beyond that, I don't know what this question means.

Answer (score 0):

As @s_ha_dum has said in his answer, you need to create a second sidebar and call it. To expand on his answer:

1) Register the sidebar. Put the following in `functions.php`:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Second Homepage Sidebar',
'id' => 'second-homepage-sidebar',
'description' => 'Secondary sidebar for the homepage',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
}
```

2) Duplicate `sidebar.php` and rename the file `sidebar-two.php`.

3) Change the sidebar id referenced in `sidebar-two.php`, e.g.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) : ?>

<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-homepage-sidebar' ) ) : ?>

<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'second-homepage-sidebar' ); ?>
```

3) In either `home.php` or `front-page.php` (depending on how your website is set up), you need to call both sidebars:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar('two'); ?>
```

4) Start adding widgets to your sidebar in the WP admin.